# Page redirection after Ajax request in javascript

Tags: jquery, django

I send a ajax post request with jquery:

```
$(function(){

    $(".palcesubm").click(function(){
        var location = $('#detail_address').val()
        $.post('/wechat/locate/select/current/',{'location':location})
    })

});
```

In my view, I can receive this request. Then I save the data in seesion, and redirect the request to another url with HttpResponseRedirect

```
@csrf_exempt
def confirm_location(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        lat = request.session.get('latitude')
        lng = request.session.get('longitude')
        area, detail_address = get_area_and_detail_address(lat, lng)

        t= loader.get_template('confirm_location.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'area':area, 'detail_address': detail_address}))
        return HttpResponse(html)

    else:
        request.session['location'] = request.POST.get('location')
        redirect_url = '/wechat/stores/direct/list?first_level='+ str(request.session.get('first_level'))

        print redirect_url
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Here is the redirected url's view

```
def direct_store_list(request):

    first_level = request.GET.get('first_level')
    request.session['first_level'] = first_level
    store_level_list = get_store_level_list(first_level)
    merchant_list = []
    location =''

    lat = request.session.get('latitude')
    lng = request.session.get('longitude')
    if request.session.get('telphone') is None:
        if request.session.get('location') is None:
            location = get_store_location(lat,lng)
        else:
            location = request.session.get('location')
            del request.session['location']
    else:
        if request.session.get('location') is None:
            location = get_user_default_location(request.session.get('telphone'))
        else:
            location = request.session.get('location')
            del request.session['location']

    merchant_list = get_merchant_list(first_level,lat,lng)

    t= loader.get_template('direct_store_list.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'store_level_list':store_level_list, 'merchant_list':merchant_list,
                             'location':location}))

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In the terminal, http response 200 OK, but page don't redirect to this page as normal HttpResponseRedirect. How to solve this problem? Thanks

```
[23/Oct/2014 14:34:23] "POST /wechat/locate/select/current/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[23/Oct/2014 14:34:24] "GET /wechat/stores/direct/list?first_level=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2452
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the request with AJAX ($.post) what will you be redirecting ? The solution you can send the URL to redirect to and do window.location = redirectionURL in your $.post response handling.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code in your JS to handle the result of the Ajax post, so nothing will happen.

However if you want to redirect, I don't understand why you are using Ajax at all: just do a normal POST.